# Jekyll liquid syntax for loading _data subfolders for Staticman comments?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I’m trying to set up staticman comments and have gotten all the code implemented to save comments correctly, but the comments are not loading.

My site has multiple types of pages so I have recipe comments save in `_data/comments/recipes/recipe-name/entry12233445430320.yml`

The problem is in this code:

```
{% assign urlslug = page.url | remove:'.html' | remove_first:'/' | split: '/' %}
  {% assign urlfolder = urlslug[0] %}
  {% assign urlfilename = urlslug[1] %}
  <p>folder: {{urlfolder}}</p><p>filename: {{urlfilename}}</p>
  <h2>{{post_slug}}</h2>

  {% if site.data.comments.recipes[urlfilename] %}
        <!-- Start static comments -->
        <div id="comments" class="js-comments">
          <h2 class="page__section-label">
            {% if site.data.comments.recipes[urlfilename].size > 1 %}
              {{ site.data.comments.recipes[urlfilename] | size }}
            {% endif %}
            Comments test 1
          </h2>
          <h2> {{ site.data.comments.recipes[urlfilename] }} </h2>
    {% assign comments = site.data.comments.recipes[urlfilename] | sort | where_exp: 'entry', 'comment[1].replying_to_uid == blank' %}
    <h3>a: {{ comments }} </h3>
    <h3>b: {{ comments[0] }} </h3>
    {% for comment in comments %}
      <h3>comment test 2</h3>
      {% assign index       = forloop.index %}
      <!-- {% assign replying_to = comment[1].replying_to | to_integer %}
      {% assign avatar      = comment[1].avatar %} -->
      {% assign email       = comment[1].email %}
      {% assign name        = comment[1].name %}
      {% assign url         = comment[1].url %}
      {% assign date        = comment[1].date %}
      {% assign message     = comment[1].message %}
      {%- assign uid             = comment[1]._id %}
      {% include comment.html index=index replying_to=replying_to avatar=avatar email=email name=name url=url date=date message=message %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <!-- End static comments -->
  {% endif %}
```

I'm successfully accessing the right comment and printing it on the page in raw format, but I can't make it print the comment correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.